# Post in feeds with Link Facebook Graph API (Titanium Studio app)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium

I'm trying to post feed through my app created in Titanium studio.

Code:

```
var data = {
        //message : '',
        link : 'http://www.google.com',
        name : 'Google',
        description : 'test post'
};
fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed', data, "POST", function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        //go nicely
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
                 //go crazy
        } else {
                alert("Unknown result");
        }
}
```

Now I have two FB app (App_ID). Assume one is **Test FB share** and second is **Original FB share**

**Test FB share** and **Original FB share** both work perfectly for iOS.

For the **Test FB share** this code works and post are shared on FB feeds. No issue.

But For **Original FB share** it fails in Android and the "go crazy" part in code above is executed.
Value of response `e` is `{"path":"me/feed","code":-1,"error":"Invalid parameter","success":false}`.

Error Log:

```
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule: (Thread-4237) [6627,35015] Request error for 'me/feed' call: Invalid parameter
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule: com.facebook.android.FacebookError: Invalid parameter
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule:  at com.facebook.android.Util.parseJson(Util.java:303)
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule:  at facebook.TiRequestListener.onComplete(TiRequestListener.java:88)
[ERROR] :  FacebookModule:  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:276)
```

**Orignal FB share** works when `data` is as follows:

```
var data = {
    message : 'A',
};
```

or

```
var data = {
    message : 'A',
    name : 'Google',
    description : 'test post'
};
```

Now it seems something is wrong with **Original FB share**. But I looked into FB App and did not find anything which may solve this problem. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

In FB app -> Settings -> Migrations Tab -> turn off 'Stream post URL security (Links in stream posts must go to app's Canvas or Website URL.)'